# localStorage.getItem gives null while I see the item in my storage stack - Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I use localStorage to store my auth token in it. 
After setting item in storage I could not fetch it again! It's while I can see the item in my browser local storage stack.

Also, when I fetch and console the item exactly after set, It's Ok and the console logs my item.

**Note:**
All my doing is just for user authentications and so on in an **Angular 4** SPA. when I want to check my token in a component's constructor, gives me null!

**Update:**
Here is the code that I use:

in `AuthService.ts` after getting token:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', itemData);
```

and it's the hole `AuthService.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public token: string;
  public userRole: number;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.initCurrentUser();
  }

  initCurrentUser() {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currrentUser'));

    this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    this.userRole = currentUser && currentUser.role;
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.token;
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.token = null;
    this.userRole = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login',
      {email: email, password: password})
      .map((response: Response) => {
        try {
          let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
          if (token) {
            this.token = token;

            let itemData= JSON.stringify({email: email, token: token});
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', itemData);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

and finally, in `HomeComponent.ts`, to check authentication:

```
 constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
    auth.initCurrentUser();
    console.log('Home', auth.token); // That gives me a null!
  }
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you place also also your code

Comment: @KrzysztofLa  I added some code. Is it enough to understanding?

Comment: where is getCredentials() in authService?

Comment: @Vega yes it is.

Comment: So where is it ?

Comment: i'm sorry, that was my mistake, I updated the Q. so the getCredentials is not exist.

Comment: No! it's null yet! I use Json parse because my item value is an object.

Comment: I think its not related to JSON.parse(). because I get even a normal string item that saved before. but if I set Item in constructor and get it immediately it will work!

Comment: It is a wild guess but can you check if the problem exists when you invoke your  auth.initCurrentUser(); in ngOnInit() instead of constructor?

Comment: I second @KrzysztofLa - you shouldn't initialize variables in the constructor, you should do that in ngOnInit()

Comment: @StephenR.Smith yes I agree but this is not about good practice right now. Just wanted to check if he will get data when ngOnInit is called.

Comment: I put my fetching logic in ngOnInit() and everything worked! I also write another method to checking authentication and in it I get user infos from local storage manually every time (not by checking the auth service token).

Comment: You should write up an answer for your own question, and post it in the answer section, then select it as the correct answer (you may have to wait for a day after you post the answer before you can accept it). That way anyone looking to solve this issue in future will have a solution they can find.

Comment: sure, its exactly what I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every authentication check I had checked token that I had in auth service and I think that was the point.

I put the `initCurrentUser()` method in `ngOnInit` instead of constructor. and in every authentication checking I fetch the user data from local storage and process some on it to checking user authentication.

So the below is my final code that solved my problem:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currrentUser'));
    if (currentUser) {
      this.token = currentUser.token;
      this.userRole = currentUser.role;
    } else {
      console.log('not get on init!');
    }
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    this.token = JSON.parse(data) && JSON.parse(data).token;
    this.userRole = JSON.parse(data) && JSON.parse(data).role;
    return !!this.token;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mistakenly placed the key instead of value. Make sure you pass them in a correct order:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```